# Anypoint Studio 7.11.1 Shared Flows not showing in debugger

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio

[image: debug view]
I am trying to debug shared flows within a mule app. (Mac Monetrey,Anypoint 7.11.1). I am unable to see debugger showing Flow Ref of shared flows as the call goes from mule app flows to shared flows, but instead it opens up shared flow xml files. The Share Flow Ref's does not change at all.

In the attached image Authentication_FR is a flow reference in the main mule app which call the shared flow (imported using import tag). The Flow Ref never changes (always showing Authentication_FR) but share flow xml gets opened as i step thru the debugger.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Is the called flow a sub-flow or a private flow?

Comment: The shared flows are <sub-flow>

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are facing a current product limitation. There is a submitted [idea](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/ideas#08734000000GO3VAAW) in order to implement this into future Anypoint Studio releases.

As a workaround you could remove the XML import tags and directly add the XML file(s) containing the shared flow(s) into the src/main/mule folder of the project you are debugging. Once you complete the debugging activities you will need to bring your project back to its original state.

Comment: Thanks Victor.

But in older version of Anypoint Studio 7.5.1. I am able to see debugger displaying the shared flow name when it executes shared flows along with variables that add/change during execution of the shared flows. 

That is all i was expecting, not that show/display the shared flows as the execution moves on the screen as it does with the app flows. Just the debugger display the values of vars etc.

Is this a limitation with 7.11.1 do you know.

Thanks

Comment: Then it may be a regression. You should report it as a possible bug if you are a customer or wait to see if it changes in the next release.